# Kotlin - Autofill SMS without READ_SMS permission

Tags: kotlin, sms-retriever-api

I need to do a feature to read the OTP from SMS and fill my field.

The only way today to do it is using SMS Retriever API from Google?

Nothing without a 3rd party lib?

I mean, Apple has it native.

We are avoiding using Retriever API because we don't want to change the SMS template we have.

Is there something that I can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative that is available now is to use SMS consent API, other than that it's not possible to detect the SMS now.

You can check about this by following the below link

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request